# Allow Remote Access To PhPMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, server, firewall

I have done everything i could find in multiple instructions on the internet that i have googled for centos 6 i have this config for phpmyadmin [HERE](http://pastebin.com/0neRKa3L) I am trying to allow it from any address but i couldnt figure it out so i decided to test it with my ip address to see if it would let me connect it wont even with it requiring my ip when it was at default settings with it just having all my "Allow from All" it would even display for the localhost of the machine all it would display on both my computer and the server is

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at localhost Port 80
```

I am unsure as to what im suppose to do from here

Thanks

Comment: Yes and no and even it i allow the localhost ip it still says forbidden if i use the server vnc

Comment: Did you set the permissions to the phpmyadmin directory?

Comment: i didnt touch the permissions is all what comes with it when i type

yum install phpmyadmin

Comment: You are correct, you should not need to change permissions. Have you tried adding `Options FollowSymLinks` and `DirectoryIndex index.php` at the top of your `<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>` section?